# text-overflow ellipsis in breadcrumb - height

Tags: css

I have breadcrumb menu with a long category name. When I add a text-overflow ellipsis to the last category name, the two breadcrumbs before are deeper then the last one. How to get a equal height in the middle of the breadcrumb.

I made a Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0rdeyhst/

```
    <div itemprop="breadcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" id="breadcrumbs">
<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="icon-home"><a itemprop="item" href="#" accesskey="h"><span itemprop="name">Home</span><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></a></span>
&nbsp;»&nbsp;<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="#" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">Caegory</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="2"></span>&nbsp;»&nbsp;<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a href="#" itemprop="item"><h1><span itemprop="name">This is a long category name adsfl lkajdlfjasldfjasdfasdf asdfadf</span></h1></a><meta itemprop="position" content="3"></span>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: you can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/0rdeyhst/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, browsers set margins to  tags, and overflow hidden causes some text alignment problems. So you should add these 2 properties into your CSS

```
#breadcrums h1 {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The h1 tag is displayed **block** by default, while your span elements are displayed **inline**.

the **display: inline** does not respect any margins and or paddings that you have added to the element, however the **display: inline-block** does.

if you change the display property of your #breadcrumbs h1, This problem is solved. But because the display: inline won't respect the width of the h1 element your overflow: ellipsis will break.

Therefore, I recommend to use flexbox.

```
#breadcrumbs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I highly recommend you to read this guide to understand what is happening:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. When I use display:inline the ellipsis is not working anymore. Any help?

Comment: I eddited my answer, please let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following css-rules to your H1-tag:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```